# Cross referencing two excel files or (Sheet 1) A1:A2500 "contains" (Sheet 2) A5

Tags: excel, contains, cross-reference

I am trying to figure out how to cross reference two different excel files to compile a sheet with all the information that I need.

Personally I am dealing with VINs and analysis details but the example below will work.

I have one file (Sheet 1) with entries (Column A), and on this same sheet I have all my analysis information that I have done (Column E).

Sheet 1:

```
       **A**                       **E** 
 **1** Franklin                    Shoots
 **2** George                      Drives
 **3** Joe                         Runs
 **4** Mikel                       Bikes
 **5** Rob                         Swims
```

In a separate file I have names in a different order and some are only partials.

Sheet 2:

```
       **A**                       **F**
 **1** John
 **2** Mike
 **3** Rob
 **4** Frank
 **5** Rich
```

I want the analysis from sheet 1 to show up in the corresponding cell in sheet 2 Column F.  The biggest thing I'm hung up on is when using "contains", I can't get (Sheet2) "(asterisk)A1(asterisk)" to work, and I don't want to go through and type (asterisk)John(asterisk), because my file is about 2500 rows with no duplicates, as opposed to 5, so I might as well individually search each one if I am going to do that. 
For example Column F on sheet 2 should read:

```
     **F**
     "No"
     Bikes
     Swims
     Shoots
     "No"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple VLOOKUP formula - in Sheet2!F2 place this formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&A2&"*",Sheet1!$A:$E,5,0),"No")
```

Comment: This will only pull the analysis from Rob, therefore the Column F in sheet 2 will look only have Swims in F3 and have no in the rest.  I want Frank to be found in Franklin and Mike to be found in Mikel.  This is the exact part I'm having trouble with, to do a contains A2, as opposed to contains Mike.

Comment: Bingo, thanks.  So, "*"&A2&"*". That is the key, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MATCH` function in conjunction with the `OFFSET` function as shown below ...

Put the following in Sheet2!F1 & fill down ...

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,MATCH("*"&A1&"*",Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5,0)-1,4),"No")
```

This produced:

```
No
Bikes
Swims
Shoots
No
```

Comment: Thanks, the "*"&A1&"*" is where I was hung up on.  Thank you

Comment: how do you type an asterisk on here without italicizing the text?